# permission denied to write into /var/www/ folder

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

My python application is using the `sentence_transformers` package and it tries to write into the `/var/www/` directory on my ubuntu system.

This is the error it is currently showing:

```
Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980245 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396] mod_wsgi (pid=50371): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/flaskapp/production.wsgi'.
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980302 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396] mod_wsgi (pid=50371): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/flaskapp/production.wsgi'.
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980465 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980514 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/production.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980520 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]     from run_app import app as application
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980531 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/run_app.py", line 4, in <module>
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980536 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]     import utils as helper
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980546 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980551 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]     model = SentenceTransformer('stsb-roberta-large')
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980561 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/SentenceTransformer.py", line 81, in __init__
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980566 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]     model_path_tmp = snapshot_download(model_name_or_path,
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980577 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   File "/var/www/html/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sentence_transformers/util.py", line 424, in snapshot_download
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980582 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]     os.makedirs(nested_dirname, exist_ok=True)
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980592 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980597 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980607 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980611 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980621 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980625 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]     makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980635 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980640 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]     mkdir(name, mode)
[Thu Aug 19 18:33:32.980640 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 50371:tid 140121496090368] [client 95.138.162.70:43396]   PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/.cache'
```

Permission setting of the `/var/www` directory:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:/var$ ls -l
total 48
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Aug 18 19:38 www
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Aug 19 13:24 backups
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root   4096 Aug 19 11:03 cache
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   4096 Apr 30 23:25 crash
drwxr-xr-x 39 root root   4096 Aug 18 19:38 lib
drwxrwsr-x  2 root staff  4096 Apr 15  2020 local
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      9 Apr 30 23:15 lock -> /run/lock
drwxrwxr-x 10 root syslog 4096 Aug 18 19:38 log
drwxrwsr-x  2 root mail   4096 Apr 30 23:15 mail
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Apr 30 23:15 opt
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      4 Apr 30 23:15 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root   4096 Apr 30 23:36 snap
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Apr 30 23:17 spool
drwxrwxrwt  7 root root   4096 Aug 19 18:11 tmp
```

Would it be ideal to set `chmod 777` for `/var/www/`?

Comment: `chmod 777` is never a good idea. BTW: It's not about permission, it's also about who's permissions those are!

Comment: What @UlrichEckhardt said: not a good idea, never (unless it's `/tmp` and the sticky bit is set).  I'd consider making the group of the user who runs the uWSGI app the owner and give the group write permissions.  But, too, only holds true if you're not going to run several websites in parallel. If you did the latter create a subdirectory under `/var/www` per app and have different ownerships.  You could go more granular and create the `.cache` and make THAT owned by the group.

Comment: @tink, that makes sense now. However, I am still not sure how I give the group write permission. Could you please advise.

Comment: e.g. `touch /var/www/.cache; chgrp www-data /var/www/.cache; chmod g+w /var/www/.cache`

Comment: @tink Thank you! Your solution works for me!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do that (777).

Be granular (see comments above).

```
touch /var/www/.cache
chgrp www-data /var/www/.cache
chmod g+w /var/www/.cache
```